# Run C program from shell script

Tags: c, bash, shell, awk

I have a C program called sign.c in the same directory as a script I want to call it from.  How would I call it from the script?  Here is the script below.  Is there anything I have to add to call it like so? I am rather new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc  -osign sign.c

% sign < /usr/share/dict/words | sort | awk -f squash.awk > out
```

Comment: Replace `% sign` by `./sign`.

Comment: or `export PATH=${PATH}:${PWD}; sign ...`.